Computing $\frac{x - y}{x - z}$ when $x,y,z$ are close to each other
What is the most stable way to compute
$$\frac{x - y}{x - z}$$
when $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all close to each other? I would like to compute expressions of this form in low precision on a GPU, but when I do so, I find that rounding errors really mess up the computation.
A straightforward implementation subtracts two numbers that are close to each other, and divides two numbers that are near zero. Neither of these operations is advisable.
I played around with the expression for a bit, trying to find a mathematical transformation that gives the same result without doing questionable numerical operations. However, couldn't figure out any good transformations.

You might be interested in https://herbie.uwplse.org/  and https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/37561/automatic-finite-differences

If your inputs are $x,y,z$, this computation is not unstable, but ill-conditioned. That's worse, because it means that a small change in your input (such as a previous approximation as a floating-point number) causes a large change in your output.
In practical terms, this means that this is the wrong subproblem to focus on. If all you have is $x,y,z$ stored as floating point numbers, then you have already lost the battle.
Either you have some more properties on $x,y,z$ (such as them coming from a finite difference, see my question linked in a comment by NNN, or there is no hope of obtaining an accurate result.

If @Nick Alger has only $x,y,z$ stored as floating point numbers, perhaps the only thing that could help is an arbitrary precision library.

@NNN Not really, you have already lost. If your true data are x=1 and y=1.0000000000000123456789, but you only have access to their floating point approximations xfp=1 and yfp=1.00000000000001, no arbitrary precision library can ever recover those 23456789 digits because it does not have access to them in the first place. OP needs to consider this problem together with the previous steps, not just as a separate problem. Maybe those x,y come from a finite difference? Then there are tricks that could help.

Main source of instability here is that when all numbers are very close to each other,- expression approaches indeterminate form $\frac 00$. Add GPU rounding errors and it becomes obvious why you get unstable results. We can't get rid much of floating point rounding errors, because it's built-in into GPU floating point format, but we can try to get rid of indeterminate form mathematical uncertainty. For that try to compute expression
$$ \frac {1}{1-z/x} - \frac {y}{x-z} ,$$
which is mathematically equivalent to your given one, but is more stable, because now you will not have indeterminate forms $0/0$, assuming $y \neq 0$ and $z \neq 0$.
As a test shot, I have tried such variables,

x=1.00010000521010  
y=1.00010000521020  
z=1.00010000521030

Then I have changed $x$ accordingly ,

|       x        |
|----------------|
|1.00010000521015|
|1.00010000521018|
|1.00010000521019|

Then I have noticed that relative error between steps of old and new expressions differs radically :

|   Err_Old (%)   |   Err_New (%)   |
|-----------------|-----------------|
|33.4072431633408 | 33.4814814817031|
|49.9999999999999 | 24.9999999997805|
|45.4545454545456 | 9.09090909099427|

Which shows that second expression converges gracefully, while original one- jumps in error and later re-considers back.
Note: do not expect black magic here, because these may be false result, due to not enough points taken (I have played with LibreCalc, so...). Besides results may depend on exact $x,y,z$ values taken and how they converges. In addition , GPU floating point inaccuracy may even spoil this small advantage. However, worth a try.
HTH!

Thanks! I tried this now in my example. It helped a little bit, but not enough.

Good to hear. Well, progress goes on with little-by-little, radical optimizations are rare. It would be interesting if you could run your calculations on CPU and compare results with GPU, to check the root cause of problems,- maybe you have reached GPU rounding limits ?

Yes it is definitely the GPU rounding. I've been running the same thing on CPU for a while, and only encountered these problem now that I am moving it to the GPU.

Try to run GPU computations in double-precision mode or you are out-of-luck. Also since this is a particular hardware issue, I would recommend posting your problem to some GPU manufacturer site like, nvidia forum and the likes.

Per the answer of Federico Poloni, I think I this is a theoretical issue with what I am doing, not really a problem with the hardware. I have tried in double precision on the GPU and it works just fine (the same as CPU). The downside is that doing double precision on the GPU makes it much slower.

In a quick test using $x, y, z$ randomly selected from $[0.99, 1.10]$, average error with the proposed replacement is worse than the original. This is not surprising given the accumulation of additional rounding error, compared to the original computation. Per Sterbenz lemma, when using finite-precision binary floating-point arithmetic, subtraction of two operands is exact if they are within a factor of two of each other (this should be true for both $x-y$ and $x-z$ based on OP's specifications). Only the division contributes rounding error.

@njuffa Have you run your test on GPU with 16-bits (low precision) floating point operations ? Because my answer exactly solves problem for low precision floating point numbers or so to say for rounding errors, which seems you are ignoring now.

FWIW, the question does not specify FP16. However, Sterbenz lemma applies to FP16 as well, regardless of platform. If you are referring to 16-bit floating-point computations that work substantially different from IEEE-754, I cannot speak to that, as my 20 year experience with GPUs is limited to NVIDIA hardware. I would suggest looking at the issue statistically (i.e. large number of random test cases at minimum), rather than relying on a "test shot".
